# how to keep alert dialog appear when displaying toast in validation radio button inside that alert dialog

Tags: android, validation, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have a radio button inside Alert dialog, and then iam validate the radio button if there is no selected radio it will display Toast message and alert dialog must be keep appear. But with my code below alert dialog will closed when displaying toast.

```
private void showPopupSubscribe() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.paket_subscribe, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.logo_1);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.subscription_package);
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgSubscribe);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int selected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (selected == R.id.rbA) {
                smsCode = vv0;
            } else if (selected == R.id.rbB) {
                smsCode = vv1;
            } else if (selected == R.id.rbC) {
                smsCode = vv2;
            } else if (selected == R.id.rbD) {
                smsCode = vv3;
            }
            if (selected == -1 ){
                Toast.makeText(CatalogHomeActivity.this, "Pilih paket untuk berlangganan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
                pdSubs.show();
                doCharging();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code below.

```
private void showPopupSubscribe() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.paket_subscribe, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.logo_1);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.subscription_package);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Next", null);
        final RadioGroup radioGroup = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgSubscribe);


        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int selected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        if (selected == R.id.rbA) {
                            smsCode = vv0;
                        } else if (selected == R.id.rbB) {
                            smsCode = vv1;
                        } else if (selected == R.id.rbC) {
                            smsCode = vv2;
                        } else if (selected == R.id.rbD) {
                            smsCode = vv3;
                        }
                        if (selected == -1 ){
                            Toast.makeText(CatalogHomeActivity.this, "Pilih paket untuk berlangganan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else {
                            pdSubs.show();
                            doCharging();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your your solution, i allready try your code but the positive button doesn't appear..

Answer (score 0):

first of all delete setPositiveButton();
and then setpositive button
after that dissmiss dialog if you want in setOnShowListener

```
 ...
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            ...
            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (selected == -1 ){
                                Toast.makeText(CatalogHomeActivity.this, "Pilih paket untuk berlangganan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }else {
                                pdSubs.show();
                                doCharging();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```